# Searching for dates in an Excel array and sending an email when that date value is within a certain range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to send an email to remind people to get recertified.

The idea is to have an array, where names are on the left and the equipment they are certified to use is along the top. Where the column and row cross has the date that person was certified on that machine. Should that date be within a certain range, then send an email to that person.
[image: Date array]

Previously, I made code for a different setup, which was a list.
[image: Previous setup]

This was much simpler, and relied on an offset from the first column. I figured out how to make it compare the date to the current date, without that "days since training" column.

I'm stuck on making it cross-compare, instead of working off of offsets.

```vb
Sub CreateCourseCertificates()
Dim EApp As Object
Set EApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim EItem As Object
Dim RList As Range
Set RList = Range("A2", Range("a2").End(xlDown))
Dim R As Range
For Each R In RList
    If (DateDiff("d", R.Offset(, 3).Value, Now)) >= 335 And (DateDiff("d", R.Offset(, 3).Value, Now)) < 365 Then
        Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
        With EItem
            .To = R.Offset(, 2).Value
            .Subject = "You're due for retraining and certification"
            .Body = "Hello, " & R & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
            & "Your certification has nearly expired. You have " & (365 - (DateDiff("d", R.Offset(, 3).Value, Now))) & " days until it expires."
            .Send
        End With
    ElseIf (DateDiff("d", R.Offset(, 3).Value, Now)) > 365 Then
        Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
        With EItem
            .To = R.Offset(, 2).Value
            .Subject = "You're overdue for retraining and certification"
            .Body = "Hello, " & R & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
            & "Your certification has expired. You are " & ((DateDiff("d", R.Offset(, 3).Value, Now)) - 365) & " days overdue."
            .Send
        End With
    End If
Next

Set EApp = Nothing
Set EItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

It'd also be great if there was a way for the email body to indicate the equipment to be retrained on, but a simple reminder would be good.

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track for the most part.   Within your For Each loop iterate through the columns for your Dates  You can use R.Column to determine which Date and Equipment are to be used.  I would also suggest creating one email per Operator with each piece of equipment they need to recert on.

Comment: @FrankBall I tried to use R.Column instead of the offset, but it was giving an error. Now I am trying to get it to search through column "i," where at the end of each loop, i is added to again, but it seemingly isn't working. No clue how to get this to work honestly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After slamming my head into the wall for a few hours I came up with a solution. Instead of having variable "R" refer to just a column, "R" now refers to a range of cells. The program looks through each "R" instance, and when it sees that a certification has expired, it uses an offset depending on the "R" cell's position in the row and column to get the Name, Email, and Equipment name and write the email. Thank you to @FrankBall for the help. Find attached my solution that has (so far) been working excellently.

```
Sub CreateCourseCertificates()
Dim EApp As Object
Set EApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim EItem As Object
Dim RList As Range
Set RList = Range("C4", "F6")
Dim R As Range
For Each R In RList
    If IsEmpty(R) = False Then
        If (DateDiff("d", R.Value, Now)) >= 335 And (DateDiff("d", R.Value, Now)) < 365 Then
            columnNum = R.Column - 3
            rowNum = R.Row - 3
            Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
            With EItem
                .To = R.Offset(, -(R.Column - 2))
              
                .Subject = "You're due for retraining and certification"
                .Body = "Hello, " & R.Offset(, -(R.Column - 1)) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                & "Your certification with the " & R.Offset((-(R.Row - 3)), 0) & " has almost expired. You have " & (365 - (DateDiff("d", R.Value, Now))) & " days until it expires."
                .Display
            End With
        ElseIf (DateDiff("d", R.Value, Now)) > 365 Then
            Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
            With EItem
                .To = R.Offset(, -(R.Column - 2))
                
                .Subject = "You're overdue for retraining and certification"
                .Body = "Hello, " & R.Offset(, -(R.Column - 1)) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                & "Your certification with the " & R.Offset((-(R.Row - 3)), 0) & " has expired. You are " & ((DateDiff("d", R.Value, Now)) - 365) & " days overdue for retraining."
                .Display
            End With
        End If
    End If
    Next

Set EApp = Nothing
Set EItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

I want to also thank this forum for its continued support.